# Properly passing information to a prototype

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype

Only using javascript.

I want to create a prototype called Table that gets all table values such the array that contains all information, how many rows are going to be displayed, the default rows that are going to be displayed, etc.

With AJAX i'm getting the query and parsing to json, then giving to loadTable the jsonArrayList so I can dynamically create the table depending on how many rows the user want to be displayed.

I am not able to give to the prototype the Array (jsonObj.aaData), i guess is not in the scope and ends being undefined, how do i do it correctly?

```
    function loadQuery() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    //parse to JSON, sends arrayList to loadTable
     var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
   // function to create the table
   //loadTable(jsonObj.aaData);

   //does not work
   var table_info = new Table(jsonObj.aaData);

    }
  };

  display_number = refreshDropdown();

  xhttp.open("GET", "server_processing2.php?iDisplayStart=1&iDisplayLength=" + display_number, true);

  xhttp.send();

}
```

The thing is creating an instance that all functions can see and extract the information from that instance instead of passing parameters from one function to another.

```
    function Table(jsonArrayL){
  this.jsonArrayL = jsonArrayL;
  this.default_rows = 25;
}
```

Comment: So where is the code that declares/defines "Table"?

Comment: Could you do `console.log(jsonObj)` after `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);` and share the output?

Comment: At the top of the file, edited in OP

Comment: @AyushChaudhary Gives a correct output: Object
aaData
:
Array[10]
0
:
Array[4]
1
:
Array[4]
2
:
Array[4]
3
:
Array[4]
4
:
Array[4]
5
:
Array[4]
6
:
Array[4]
7
:
Array[4]
8
:
Array[4]
9
:
Array[4]
length
:
10
__proto__
:
Array[0]
iTotalDisplayRecords
:
"9889388"
iTotalRecords
:
"9889388"
sEcho
:
0
sql
:
"↵  SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS `id`, `event_date`, `ip_src`, `domain_destination`↵  FROM   proxylog_proxyentry↵  ↵  ↵  LIMIT 1, 10↵  "
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Ok, now define "does not work". What error are you getting?

Comment: @ScottMarcus When i call the instance from another function i'm getting pagination.js:13 Uncaught ReferenceError: table_info is not defined(…)

Comment: @Chalsy Then that other function is the faulty one, not the one creating `table_info`. Make sure the function is in scope and doesn't get called before the data was loaded. `loadTable(jsonObj.aaData);` (with an appropriate `loadTable` function) seemed to be exactly the correct approach.

Comment: @Chalsy That error has nothing to do with your Table. It's simply that `table_info` is declared (scoped) to your `onreadystatechange` callback function and is not in scope from another function. You just need to make the declaration of your variable in a high enough scope to access it from all the locations you'll want to.

Comment: @Chalsy Also, you may want to stop using the word "prototype" in this context as you are not actually using/making a JavaScript protoype. Your Table function is a "Constructor Function" that uses the native "Function" object as its prototype.